# Doubly-compound leaf examples?

Tags: botany, terminology, plant-anatomy, trees, morphology

I've got a project where we collect leaves, classify them, etc. There are some required classifications. One of the requirements is to get a doubly-compound leaf. What are some trees that are doubly-compound? Please help! I have Hickory, but that's just compound I think.

Edit: I did try googling, but it's hard for me to know what's available in my region.

**From Comments:** *I live in Tennessee, U.S.*

Comment: Where in the world are you? What kind of trees/plants do you have access to?

Comment: I live in Tennessee.

Comment: Hickories are not doubly compound (AKA *bipinnate*). They are just (once) compound leaves as you guessed.

Comment: For the future, you can try Weakley's flora app "[FloraQuest](http://www.floraquest.com/)". You can search for trees based on a dichotomous key and fortunately It'll automatically narrow your choices so you can only see local plants. Though this won't give you a list, it'll train you to use a valuable tool while searching for your own answers. (Note: it comes with a visual glossary of terms :D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Albizia julibrissin* (Persian silk tree)** is doubly compound (AKA ***bipinnate***) and has a conspicuous pink/white fluffy flower. This tree is an Asian native, but it's a commonly cultivated (and equally commonly escaped) plant in the U. S. You should be able to find it in numerous locations. Look in yards and along roads.

[image: Albizia julibrissin]
http://www.missouriplants.com/Pinkalt/Albizia_julibrissin_plant.jpg

For native species: ***Gleditsia triacanthos* (honeylocust)** is a fairly widespread (though uncommon) example of bipinnate leaves. Here is an image from Will Cook's wonderful [website](http://www.carolinanature.com):

[image: Gleditsia triacanthos]

Answer (score 1):

Many ferns have multiply-compound leaves

Take the one in this image, for instance:

[image]

That structure is one doubly-compound leaf.

Answer (score 1):

Most plants of the **caesalpinioideae** subfamily of the leguminosae family are bipinnate, i.e., doubly compound. The best, and perhaps the most easily accesible one for you would have to be ***tamarind***.

[image: Tamarind leaves]